# Am I understanding how to import my .csv file into sqlite?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, csv

I currently have a .csv file with several unlabeled columns of data, which to my knowledge translate to the following datatypes in sqlite:

- datetime (in the format 7/19/2011  12:00:00 PM) -> numeric
- double -> real
- char(1) -> text
- float -> real

I can create the database by doing the following:

```
sqlite> create table myTable (myVar1 numeric, myVar2 real, myVar3 text, myVar4 real);
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import myFile.csv myTable
```

Then I copy and paste the newly created myTable.db into the "assets" folder in my project in eclipse. I make a DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, and then I can start using and reading from the database in my Android project.

Am I getting this right? I've never used a database before and I've seen so many vastly different instructions on doing this. Some of my questions are-- do I have to label the columns of my .csv file?  Is my .csv file not "simple" enough to just use .import and I'll need to find a program to translate it? I've come across sites saying that I need to rename something (which I don't seem to have) to "_id", and I don't know what this is, where this is, or how to do this, or if it's even necessary, or what it's for. What else am I missing?

Comment: SQLite is typeless, you don't have to worry about the data type storage. http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html

Comment: @Pentium10: your link points to the docs of data types for sqlite 2, not sqlite 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting it "right" except for that first datetime column. You should use the TEXT type, not a numeric type.

Also, you can inspect your data after the import to see if all is well, especially with that datetime field:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10;
```

**UPDATE**

In response to the OP's last comment: my understanding of how you store date(time) is that it depends on your context. So if the date in the flat file is in the format "7/19/2011 12:00:00 PM", then without any transformation it'll be imported as TEXT anyway.

Comment: I was confused about the datetime bit too, but http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html suggests that it should be NUMERIC... Though perhaps that's in a different format without the AM/PM and whatnot.

Comment: +1 - Concur.  You typically want to use type affinity TEXT for dates.  Typically.

Answer (score 1):

Importing csv into database is 15 lines of code task and it gives you more control over this process.
Table columns names like "var3" are just terrible, however there is no need to rename it in database you can just use sql aliases:

```
select myVar1 _id, myVar2 from myTable
```

_id is common name for primary key column of table (it's usually numeric column witch must be unique). Every ADK class using datastore assumes relays on it, so it's nice to use this convention.
If you just want read only database you can prepare db locally and find some [tutorials](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) how to include it into your app.

Comment: I'm not naming my variables "var", my file "file", or my table "table"... It's just for the sake of the example. 
Since my database is sorted and accessed by the date/time, are you saying that this first column, rather than being called, say, myVar1, should be called _id? So I should declare it as create table myTable (_id text, myVar2 real, myVar3 text, myVar4 real); ?
And yes, I do just want a read-only database. Could you link me to one of these tutorials of which you speak?

Comment: I've linked some blog post witch seems to work. I also recommend you to become familiar with fundamental DB concepts like primary key - it's too complex subject to explain it here. Column with primary key in android should be named as "_id" type numeric and values in that column must be unique due to strictly identify single row. In **very** simplified way you can think about it as a "row number"